# How can i change text and links in the header part?

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-1.6

Please how can i change text and links in  the highlited zones in the picture below : 
[Click to see](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PZnYf.png)

Thanx a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prestashop comes with a translation mechanism. Usually from your Prestashop backend, navigate to **Localization > Translation**, then **identify "Modify Translations "**. Select the type of translation, the theme and the language and hit on the button "Modify" on the right hand side. Look for any module in the front office translations group that contains "search".

Your situation may be a little be different because you are not using the default theme. You theme developer has probably created a new quick search module. You would need to identify the actual module and it should be easy to identify it from the list of translatable module. If the module is not well developed, it will not be possible to modify them. In that case, you should ask your theme developer.

I hope it help. Good luck with your business.